# How to return SSMS generated message "Commands Completed Successfully" in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, unix

In SQL server SSMS, when stored procedures run successfully, it will show the message in message tab as "Commands Completed Successfully." .

Is there any way to capture this message as output value.

I am aware that stored procedure returns 0 if it runs successfully but I need the return value as
"Commands Completed Successfully."

P.S. I am calling procedure from Unix shell command.

Comment: Generally, if you want to capture the data from the messages pane, it's an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info), in my opinion. Why can't you use the `RETURN` value?

Comment: The completed message is displayed by the SSMS client tool, not returned by SQL Server. Is your shell command invoking SQLCMD? In that case, specify the `-b` argument so that a non-zero exit code is returned after errors. Your shell script can use that to create the desired message.

Answer (score 0):

Bottom of the Stored Procedure use select statement..

***SELECT "Commands Completed Successfully."***

**Reason:
If not success always it returns Error message and will not go in last line, so hardcoded message will make sense.**